# Split string and add code delimiters as needed

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split a text into parts each max 2000 characters long (in this example case maybe 75 so the requirements i will list work)

requirements:

- the parts i want to split the text into can only be 2000 characters long
- if there is a code block where im splitting i want to add code delimiters (```) to the end and to the start of the next part (and optional the language if there was one specified with the starting delimiter) so the code block remains intact even when split.

Example text variable containing the following:

````
text = """test text blablabla
```python
import random
import math

def random_number():
    return random.randint(0, 100)

def square_root(number):
    return math.sqrt(number)
```
more test text blablabla"""
````

Desired Output:

````
part1 = """test text blablabla
```python
import random
import math

def random_number():
    return random.randint(0, 100)
```
"""

part2 = """```python
def square_root(number):
    return math.sqrt(number)
```
more test text blablabla"""
````

Hopefully someone can undestand what im referring to, i've tried for a while now and can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Go line by line until you hit 2000 chars. As you go, check if line contains `'''python`. If hits such a line set bool "inPythonBlock" to true and search for `'''` next. When you hit 2000 mark, you have two cases - you are either in python block or outside and deal with them accrodingly

Comment: This site is not of the type "here is the problem, please supply code or at least hints". I consider the question as off-topic.

Comment: @dankal444 sounds like a good way to handle this, maybe i've overcomplicated things for myself while trying to solve this